# Prove that the forms below are exact and determine the primitive

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Prove that the forms below are exact and determine the primitive

a) $z^2 d \overline{z}+ 2 | z |^2 dz $

(i) Check if it is accurate

We know that a form w is exact if $w = df | _ {V}$ and $f$ is called the primitive of w.

So, like $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} d\overline{z}$.

We have to: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}= 2 | z |^2$

$\frac{\partial f }{\partial \overline{z}}= z^2$

Then we can use the expressions of these partial derivatives, those to formulate from the previous matter:

$\frac{\partial f }{\partial z}= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}i)$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f }{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial f }{\partial y} i)$

Then we would have to solve a system and then integrate on both sides and find out $f$.

can anybody help me ? appreciate.

Comment: $|z|^2 = z\bar z$